# Trying to update PHP servers to PHP7-cgi (7.2)

Tags: php, .htaccess, update, php7

I'm Trying to update PHP servers to php7-cgi (7.2) in my `.htaccess` file. Just not sure how exactly to edit the code, haven't been able to get it to work.

Here is the code in the `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
Redirect /prodDetail.do (weblink)    
AddType application/x-httpd-php .jsp    
AddHandler x-httpd-php .jsp


# for PHP5-CGI    
AddHandler php-cgi .php    
Action php-cgi /cgi-bin/php-cgi


# for php and securewebexchange
<IfDefine SSL>    
    AddHandler php-cgi .php    
    Action php-cgi https://secure9.securewebexchange.com/(weblink)/cgi-bin/php-cgi
</IfDefine>
```